# How can I switch to a different ajax on a click of an ASP.NET button server side?

Tags: asp.net, tabs, ajax.net

I have a set of tabs in a tab container that I can move between freely by manually clicking on the tabs or by using a javascript;  however, what I want to do is to switch between tabs using an ASP.NET serverside button.

So here's the layout.  Tab 1 has an ASP.NET Button, which, when clicked, should go to Tab 2 and display the results of a query in a gridview.  Here is the onclick code for the ASP.NET Button:

```
    protected void btnOutstandingTasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load task list by all outstanding tickets
            SqlDSOutstanding.SelectParameters.Clear();
            SqlDSOutstanding.SelectParameters.Add("1", TypeCode.Int64, "3");

            gvxTaskList.DataSourceID = null;
            gvxTaskList.DataSource = SqlDSOutstanding;
            gvxTaskList.DataBind();
            upnlTaskList.Update();

            DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex = DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex + 1;   

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Not sure why its not working, but i imagine someone out there knows how to do it.  Appreciate the help!

And here is the client side showing that the tab container is inside an update panel.

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlDispatch" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers></Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="DispatchTabs" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" CssClass="Tab" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabDashboard" runat="server" HeaderText="Dashboard" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Dashboard
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlDashboard" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: What about OnClientClick?  http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp   The OnClick will raise on the server, but OnClientClick will pop the tab over.

Comment: The first thing that jumps at me is UpdateMode="Conditional" and you don't have any triggers defined, change to UpdateMode="Always" or even remove that attribute since always is the default

Comment: Gobble, that's what i needed thank you!  I don't know how to accept your comment as an answer because there is no checkmark as you commented instead of answer.  but if you post your comment as the answer i'll accept it.  thanks again, you and Ant!

Answer (score 1):

Putting the tab container within an update panel should do the trick. Also, currently your code has a flaw, you don't want to always just add 1 to the ActiveIndex tab because you will get an out of range exception if you go beyond the last one.

```
if(DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex == DispatchTabs.Count() -1)
{
   DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex = 0;
}
else
{
   DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex = DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex + 1;  
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean about the index, thank you for that; however, the tab container is already in an update panel.  I'll add a snip of the code in the original post.  Maybe you can see something i missed.