# Server Side Redirect To Different Tab In User Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs

I know that there are countless of ways to redirect the user to other external pages using Response.Redirect and similar methods, however, **What would I have to do in order to redirect the user to different tab in tabbed interface?**

Lets say I have interface on the web site like this:

[    **Clients**   ][ **Contacts** ]

[_____ Tab 1 _____]

When user clicks on Clients (**a href="Clients"**), it displays Tab 1  , when user clicks Contacts (**a href="Contacts"**), Tab 2 is shown .

**Tab 1** has ID **Clients** and **Tab 2** has ID **Contacts**

Now, lets say there's an **asp:Button** inside the Tab 1, which executes a server side code on client click.

```
 if(true)
     //Show Tab 2 (Contacts)
 else
    //Something else
```

Everything's wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

Is there a way to do the said?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped, if not I'll dig around some more.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to help.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921675/1856992

The relevant portion will be

```
var ContactsTab
if(true)
{
   DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex = ContactsTabIndex;
}
else
{
   DispatchTabs.ActiveTabIndex = 0; // or something else.  
}
```